# Saving the original image before mouseover

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to realize JavaScript that would change image on mouseover and revert it back, when mouseout. I have this code for that:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('span[data-oe-id] img');


var i;
var imgsrc=[];
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    imgsrc[i] = list[i].src;
    console.log(imgsrc[i]);
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(event){event.target.src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/PfFtibPKBbQrK/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47b668e5062e9a561e681f23705e106d8d495b3915&rid=giphy.gif";},false);
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseout",function(event){event.target.src=imgsrc[i];},false);
}
```

It is changing image on mouseover perfectly fine, but on mouseout, image is changed to undefined. For example:

```
<img src="undefined" class="img img-fluid" alt="A4Tech Bloody V8M">
```

Is result after mouseout

Comment: Have you confirmed the imgsrc array is populating as you would expect? I see a console.log in your for loop, are you seeing the correct paths in your log?

Comment: Yep. Images are correct - https://prnt.sc/seq8i3

Answer (score 2):

Src attribute cannot be set using event argument. you can use `this` keywords to access same selected element. 

View Output in full screen

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll('img');

var i;
var imgsrc=[];
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    imgsrc[i] = list[i].src;
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function()
    {
     this.src="https://media1.giphy.com/media/PfFtibPKBbQrK/giphy.gif?cid=ecf05e47b668e5062e9a561e681f23705e106d8d495b3915&rid=giphy.gif";
     });
    list[i].addEventListener("mouseout",function()
    {
      this.src=imgsrc[i];
    });
}
```

```html
<img id="1" src="1" alt="img1"/>
<img id="2" src="2" alt="img2"/>
<img id="3" src="3" alt="img3"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but issue persists. Here is the video of this issue - https://mega.nz/file/PcdnBABK#WknWPDMMdIpS-AUplPUUNyUf33XWPZxEeiw8PEkWp80